COPS episode intro - "stop or I'll shoot you in the back!"
The reality show Cops (Fox) is currently in its 27th season(!).
However, I remember an early, early episode (definitely series 1 or 2) which featured a cop chasing a "perp" and as he ran the cop yells "stop, or I'll shoot you in the back!"
It was possibly even part of the clips used in the show intro (Bad Boys jingle).
Can anyone confirm the episode featuring the clip or the episodes featuring the scene in the introduction?
Ps. I strongly believe it to be s01e01 or 02 but the clips I've seen of the intro are missing.

I Googled "stop, or I'll shoot you in the back!" and immediately got this clip (the part you are looking for is @4:20):



Looks like it was in the pilot episode. 

You're kidding! I pictured the scene different in my head and must've skipped thru it. I knew I'd seen it but figured it must've been edited for syndication by now. I think when I searched for it a year back the comment wasn't there, so apologies for the "did you google it?" question!
